Is there way to create NDK program without need to java?
I had try this using some code produced with Ai, to create program without need to java, just only c++, but in Android studio gradle failed to compile and failed to compile code to apk.
Is there example or piece of code or way to produce app just with c++

There is repo with NDK samples: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples

Your question lacks research effort, a minimal reprodicible example and debugging details. And it is asking about 3rd party resources. So it doesn't meet SO guidelines.
